# Caching with manifest, html5

Tags: html, application-cache

File manifest.php contains data

```
ACHE MANIFEST
index.html
page.html
category.html
```

If I change name of manifest.php to new_manifest.php, will it re-cache files or use the earlier cached data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the name of the manifest file so the old manifest is not found on server anymore then the cache will be dropped and all files will be loaded from server.

Depending on how the new files and manifest are then they will be re-cached.